# Show there exists a sequence of postive real numbers s.t.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,1]$ with $\forall n\in\mathbb N, \lvert f_n(x) \rvert < +\infty$ a.e. Show there exists a sequence $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of positive real numbers s.t. $f_n(x)/c_n \rightarrow 0$ for almost every $x$ in $[0,1]$. Hint: use the borel-cantelli lemma- pick the sequence $c_n$ so that
$$m[x \in [0,1]:\frac{|f_n(x)|}{c_n}>1/n]<1/2^n$$
where m is the measure.

Comment: Can you show us ideas you have had?

Comment: I think because the borel cantelli lemma says that the set of points that belong to infinitely many measurable subsets of [0,1], is measurable and has measure zero, then the measure of the above set is 0 and thus c sub n must be a sequence of numbers that are each greater than 2^-n.

Comment: Dude seriously? You asked this question yesterday:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381780/show-there-exists-a-sequence-of-positive-real-numbers-s-t.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate